# Pandas dataframe subtracting group minima from columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that holds user ids and datetimes for certain events. Now I want to get the relative time that each event happened with respect to the first event of that specific user.

```
user_id  date
A 2016-03-02 18:15:43
A 2016-01-10 17:58:57
B 2017-03-22 07:52:00
B 2017-03-27 10:41:00
```

I found a solution that works but seems way too much effort. I believe there is a much more elegant way to do this.

```py
#get earliest datetime per user
start = lambda x: x.min()
start.__name__ = 'start_date'
min_dates = df.groupby('user_id').agg({'date':[start]})

#merge back to dataframe
df = df.join(min_dates.date['start_date'])

#calulate relative time
df['time_after_start'] = (df['date']-df['start_date']).apply(lambda x: x.days+x.seconds/(24*60*60))
```

The expected result looks like this

```
user_id  date  time_after_start                                                                   
A  2017-03-22  07:52:00  0.000000
A  2017-03-27  10:41:00  5.117361
B  2016-03-02  18:15:43  52.011644
B  2016-01-10  17:58:57  0.000000
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `min` for `Series` with same size like original `DataFrame`, then convert timedeltas by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide for `day`s:

```
s = df.groupby('user_id')['date'].transform('min')
df['time_after_start'] = (df['date']-s).dt.total_seconds()/(24*60*60)
print (df)
  user_id                date  time_after_start
0       A 2016-03-02 18:15:43         52.011644
1       A 2016-01-10 17:58:57          0.000000
2       B 2017-03-22 07:52:00          0.000000
3       B 2017-03-27 10:41:00          5.117361
```

Comment: Great! I knew that I was missing something. Thanks a lot!